# Coding while loops in VBA to copy and paste value that ends the loop

Tags: excel, loops, vba

I have two columns of data that I want to compare and then extract a value from a cell once it is less than the cell to the right.

If A is less than B copy and paste column A value to C1. I understand a while loop can help with the checking but I am unsure how to stop it checking and then taking the value from the cell in column A and pasting it into a new cell.

For example:
Column A 1.00, 1.50, 1.75, 1.95, 2.00, 2.1
Column B 0.50, 1.00, 1.50, 2.00, 2.50, 3.00
Column C 1.95

Comment: "_IF A_" is all what you can tell us?

Comment: You could add some more details, including code. Please check here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

1) Use a for loop to loop through rows
2) Use `Exit For` to exit the loop when the condition is met

```
 For intRow = 1 to 6
     if Cells(intRow, 1).value < Cells(intRow, 2).value Then
         Range("C1").value = Cells(intRow, 1).value
         Exit For
     End If
 Next intRow
```